# How to convert rows to columns - complex pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

How to construct a data set that returns the following columns using dynamic SQL.

**fed name, fed address, cfo 1 name, cfo 1 email, cfo 1 phone, cfo 2 name, cfo 2 email , cfo 2 phone, ... director 1 name, director 1 email, director 1 phone ... through 5, president 1 name etc..** All in one row.

I Have four tables in my database:

Contact:

```
X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c     |    Name          |    Email    |     Phone     |   Federation_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                           |    John Smith    | x9@gmail.com |  546-5464889 |     1
2                           |    David smith   | x8@gmail.com |  145-5464889 |     1
3                           |    Ellen Smith   | x9@gmail.com |  546-5464889 |     1
4                           |    Dan smith     | x8@gmail.com |  145-5464889 |     1
5                           |    Kelly Smith   | x9@gmail.com |  546-5464889 |     2
6                           |    Dori smith    | x8@gmail.com |  145-5464889 |     2
7                           |    Nir Smith     | x9@gmail.com |  546-5464889 |     2
8                           |    Victor smith  | x8@gmail.com |  145-5464889 |     2
```

Affiliation:

```
X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c     |    npe5__Role__c      
-----------------------------------------------
4                           |    President                  
8                           |    President
```

Federation:

```
Federation_ID   |  Name    |   Address
---------------------------------------
1               |   x      |   123 hello 
2               |   y      |   345 world
```

Constituency:

```
X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c     |    Constituency       
-----------------------------------------------
1                           |    CFO                
2                           |    CFO            
3                           |    Director               
7                           |    Director 
5                           |    Director               
6                           |    Director
```

Expected Result for Federation 1:

```
  Name    |   Address   |    CFO 1        | CFO 1 Email  | CFO 1 Phone  | CFO 2        | CFO 2 Email  | CFO 2 Phone  | Director 1  | Director 1 Email | Director 1 Phone | President 1 | President 1 Email | President 1 Phone| 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   x      |   123 hello |    John Smith   | x9@gmail.com | 546-5464889  | David smith  | x8@gmail.com | 145-5464889  | Ellen Smith | x9@gmail.com     | 546-5464889      | Dan smith   | x8@gmail.com      | 145-5464889
```

Each federation can have multiple contacts with the same constituency and affiliation.

For example a federation 'x' can have more than one CFO and more than one director. These information comes from the constituency table. (These numbers are dynamic.)

Then the same federation can have more then one president and this info comes from the affiliation table.

Here is how I started but it is not exactly doing what I am expecting.

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @pickedConstituenciesByUser varchar(MAX) = 'Chief Financial Officers,President,Executive Directors'
DECLARE @constituencies VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @constituencies = STUFF (
                            (   
                                SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + Constituency__c

                                FROM    Constituency 

                                WHERE   Active__c = 1 AND Constituency__c IN (SELECT Value FROM fnc_Split_IDs(@pickedConstituenciesByUser, ','))

                                ORDER BY '],[' + Constituency__c

                                FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 1, 2, ''
                          ) + ']'

--return 
SET @query =  
    'SELECT * FROM ' +
    '( ' +
        'SELECT  c.Name, ' +                                            
                'f.Community, ' +
                'f.CitySize, '+
                'f.CommunityCode, ' +                               
                'f.BillingStreet, ' +
                'f.BillingCity, ' +
                'f.BillingState, ' +
                'f.BillingPostalCode, ' +
                'f.BillingCountry, ' +          
                'ct.Constituency__c ' +             

        'FROM Federation f ' +

        'JOIN Contact c ON f.Account_ID = c.AccountId ' +

        'JOIN Affiliation a ON  c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c = a.npe5__Contact__c  ' + 
                                'AND ' +
                                'a.Affiliation_Type__c IN (''Professional'',''Lay'') ' +                                                                

        'JOIN Constituency ct ON ct.Contact__c = c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c AND ct.Active__c = 1 ' +         

    ') AS t ' +     

    'PIVOT (MAX(t.Name) ' + 
           'FOR t.Constituency__c IN ('+ @constituencies +')) AS pvt ' +    

    'Order BY CitySize, Community ' 

EXECUTE (@query)
```

This code returns only one CFO and one Director and no presidents.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great place to start.

Comment: I recommend against `'],[' + Constituency__c`. You should really be using `N',' + QUOTENAME( Constituency__c)

Comment: What do you mean? You are asking for help with a query but did not provide the table definition, sample data or desired output. You have 4 table names and a query that doesn't work.

Comment: The idea is to post create table statements so we aren't speculating on datatypes. And also so the people volunteering their time can just copy and paste so their time is spent working ON your problem instead of setting it up.

Comment: Why is there a requirement to make this a Dynamic sql?  Secondly, I expect that the first 5 of each are required:  for each Account for each Role the first 5 Contacts.  And for each Account for each Constituency the first 5 Contacts.  (Or else the resulting set may get enormously wide with a lot of columns).  Where there are not at least 5, then we present only what data we have.  Please confirm or clarify.  The sample data should have some such test case, and the requested results would show what is needed.

Comment: @SeanLange please let me know if this any help?

Comment: @donPablo because we do not know how many constituencies and affiliations are with in a single federation. You can only tell by querying the tables but even than the data is in rows. I want the constituencies and affiliations "title" to be columns the columns. make sense?

Comment: Yes that is much clearer thanks. In your code you have constituencies, is that the same thing as federation? So for example you might pass in 1? Do you allow for multiple values to be passed in? If so, are those value delimited somehow?

Comment: So federations and contacts are unique in each table. You can think of constituencies and affiliations, as contacts' titles and a contact belongs to a federations. You can have each contact with infinity types of constituencies and/or affiliations. I hope I am not confusing you.

Comment: So since your inbound parameter is constituencies what value would you pass in what would be the output?

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment. When we are looking for consumable data it should be easy for the person helping you to consume it. Here is how this information should be posted so others can query against it.

```
create table Contact
(
    X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c int
    , Name varchar(50)
    , Email varchar(50)
    , Phone varchar(15)
    , Federation_ID int
)

insert Contact values
(1, 'John Smith', 'x9@gmail.com', '546-5464889', 1)
, (2, 'David smith', 'x8@gmail.com', '145-5464889', 1)
, (3, 'Ellen Smith', 'x9@gmail.com', '546-5464889', 1)
, (4, 'Dan smith', 'x8@gmail.com', '145-5464889', 1)
, (5, 'Kelly Smith', 'x9@gmail.com', '546-5464889', 2)
, (6, 'Dori smith', 'x8@gmail.com', '145-5464889', 2)
, (7, 'Nir Smith', 'x9@gmail.com', '546-5464889', 2)
, (8, 'Victor smith', 'x8@gmail.com', '145-5464889', 2)

create table Affiliation
(
    X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c int
    , npe5__Role__c varchar(20)
)

insert Affiliation values
(4, 'President')                 
, (8, 'President')

create table Federation
(
    Federation_ID int
    , Name varchar(10)
    , Address varchar(20)
)

insert Federation values
(1, 'x', '123 hello')
, (2, 'y', '345 world')

create table Constituency
(
    X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c int
    , Constituency varchar(10)
)

insert Constituency values
(1, 'CFO')
, (2, 'CFO')
, (3, 'Director')
, (7, 'Director')
, (5, 'Director')
, (6, 'Director')
```

I don't have any more time to help you today. Maybe somebody else will be able to use the data I created to help.

Comment: GREAT data and a big leg up

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for trying to help.

After a whole day I was able to come up with something that works for me. It might not be the best way to handle this but it works.

Hopefully this can help someone else.

```
    DECLARE @pickedConstituenciesByUser varchar(8000) = 'Chief Financial Officers,Executive Directors,President'
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)    
    DECLARE @column_headers VARCHAR(8000)

    -- Creating the main temp table
    CREATE TABLE #Main_Tbl
    (   
        [ID]                varchar(50),
        column_value        varchar(255),                                           
        Community           varchar(255),
        CitySize            varchar(255),
        CommunityCode       varchar(255),           
        BillingStreet       varchar(255),
        BillingCity         varchar(255),
        BillingState        varchar(255),
        BillingPostalCode   varchar(255),
        BillingCountry      varchar(255),
        Title               varchar(255),
        RowNum              int,
        Column_header       varchar(255)
    )

    -- Inserting intital data with constituencies and (contact names into column_value)
    INSERT INTO #Main_Tbl
    SELECT  c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c,
            c.[Name] column_value,                                          
            f.Community,
            f.CitySize,
            f.CommunityCode,                                
            f.BillingStreet, 
            f.BillingCity, 
            f.BillingState, 
            f.BillingPostalCode, 
            f.BillingCountry, 
            ct.Constituency__c,
            0 Rownum,
            '' [Column_header]

    FROM Federation f

    JOIN Contact c ON f.Account_ID = c.AccountId                                                        

    JOIN Constituency ct ON ct.Contact__c = c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c AND ct.Active__c = 1 

    -- Inserting intital data with affiliations and (contact names into column_value)
    INSERT INTO #Main_Tbl
    SELECT  c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c,
            c.[Name] column_value,                                          
            f.Community,
            f.CitySize,
            f.CommunityCode,                                
            f.BillingStreet, 
            f.BillingCity, 
            f.BillingState, 
            f.BillingPostalCode, 
            f.BillingCountry, 
            a.npe5__Role__c,
            0 Rownum,
            '' [Column_header]          

    FROM Federation f

    JOIN Contact c ON f.Account_ID = c.AccountId

    JOIN Affiliation a ON   c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c = a.npe5__Contact__c 
                            AND 
                            a.Affiliation_Type__c IN ('Professional','Lay') 
                            AND 
                            a.npe5__Status__c = 'Current'                                                                                                                       

    -- Updating data with row number and column headers.
    UPDATE A
    SET A.RowNum = Z.RowNum, A.Column_header = z.Column_header
    FROM #Main_Tbl A
    JOIN
    (
            SELECT  x.ID,               
                    x.CommunityCode,
                    x.Community,
                    x.CitySize,
                    x.column_value,
                    x.Title,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.CommunityCode, x.Title ORDER BY x.column_value) RowNum,                
                    x.Title + ' ' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.CommunityCode, x.Title ORDER BY x.column_value) as varchar(10)) Column_header                 

            FROM #Main_Tbl x

            JOIN Contact c ON x.ID = c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c

            WHERE Title IN (SELECT Value FROM fnc_Split_IDs(@pickedConstituenciesByUser, ','))

    ) Z ON A.ID = Z.ID

    -- Inserting the same data - but this time replacing name with email into column_value 
    INSERT INTO #Main_Tbl
    SELECT  c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c,
            c.Email column_value,                                           
            x.Community,
            x.CitySize,
            x.CommunityCode,                                
            x.BillingStreet, 
            x.BillingCity, 
            x.BillingState, 
            x.BillingPostalCode, 
            x.BillingCountry, 
            x.Title,
            0 Rownum,
            x.Column_header + ' Email' [Column_header]

    FROM #Main_Tbl x

    JOIN Contact c ON x.ID = c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c 

    -- Inserting the same data again - but this time replacing email with phone into column_value 
    INSERT INTO #Main_Tbl
    SELECT  c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c,
            c.Phone column_value,                                           
            x.Community,
            x.CitySize,
            x.CommunityCode,                                
            x.BillingStreet, 
            x.BillingCity, 
            x.BillingState, 
            x.BillingPostalCode, 
            x.BillingCountry, 
            x.Title,
            0 Rownum,
            x.Column_header + ' ' + 'Phone' [Column_header]

    FROM #Main_Tbl x

    JOIN Contact c ON x.ID = c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c

    WHERE Column_header NOT LIKE ('%Email%')

    -- Inserting the same data again - but this time replacing phone with title into column_value 
    INSERT INTO #Main_Tbl
    SELECT  c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c,
            a.npe5__Role__c column_value,                                           
            x.Community,
            x.CitySize,
            x.CommunityCode,                                
            x.BillingStreet, 
            x.BillingCity, 
            x.BillingState, 
            x.BillingPostalCode, 
            x.BillingCountry, 
            x.Title,
            0 Rownum,
            x.Column_header + ' ' + 'Title' [Column_header]

    FROM #Main_Tbl x

    JOIN Contact c ON x.ID = c.X18_Digit_Contact_ID__c

    JOIN Affiliation a ON x.ID = a.npe5__Contact__c AND a.npe5__Status__c = 'Current' AND a.npe5__Role__c <> 'Constituent'

    WHERE Column_header NOT LIKE ('%Email%') AND Column_header NOT LIKE ('%Phone%')

    -- creating a string with the proper column headers
    SELECT  @column_headers = STUFF 
                              (
                                (   
                                    SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + TRIM([Column_header])

                                    FROM    #Main_Tbl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

                                    ORDER BY '],[' + TRIM([Column_header])

                                    FOR XML PATH('')
                                ), 1, 2, ''
                              ) + ']'

    -- replacing empty headers
    SET @column_headers = Replace(@column_headers, '[],', '')

    -- replacing email
    SET @column_headers = Replace(@column_headers, '[Email],', '')

    -- replacing phone
    SET @column_headers = Replace(@column_headers, '[Phone],', '')

    -- replacing title
    SET @column_headers = Replace(@column_headers, ',[Title]', '')

    -- Build main query 
    SET @query = 
        'SELECT * FROM ' +
        '( ' +

                'SELECT       Community
                            , CitySize
                            , CommunityCode
                            , BillingStreet
                            , BillingCity
                            , BillingState
                            , BillingPostalCode
                            , BillingCountry
                            , column_value                      
                            , Column_header

                 FROM #Main_Tbl ' +

        ') AS t ' +         

        'PIVOT (MAX(column_value) FOR Column_header IN ('+ @column_headers +')) AS pvt ' +

        'ORDER BY CitySize, Community' 

    -- Execute query
    EXECUTE (@query)

    DROP TABLE #Main_Tbl
```